# How to block Spiders / Scrapers by REMOTE hostname / domain for all Virtual Hosts in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, domain-name, robots.txt

I've seen plenty of robot.txt stuff, and some mod-rewrite solutions that looked promising… but haven't been able to find a simple solution to block Spiders / Scrapers / whoever the hell I want to block…  I'd rather do this by hostname / domain, as it seems simpler than relying on user-agents, etc…

For example, say I were to see this in Apache logs..

`msnbot-207-46-192-48.search.msn.com - - [07/Dec/2011:23:01:41 -0500] "GET /%3f/$/bluebox/blog/2011/iphoto/ HTTP/1.1" 404 366`

ok… I want to prevent `*.search.msn.com` from ever coming here, or any of my sites - in any of my folders - VHOST or otherwise…

Typically, I have MANY `<VirtualHost *.80>`'s setup, and DO NOT want to have to repeat the config for each host..  In that same vein, I have many `DocumentRoot`'s… and putting some file in each of them, aka `.htaccess` really isn't an option..

I had been using something in `httpd.conf` that resembled…

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BadBot [OR]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/`
```

How can i use the hostnames provided by <strike>`UseCanonicalName On`</strike> to blanket-`Deny all` any domain I so desired?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best idea to do it by host name since Apache would have to do a lookup for each request.

Why not do it with IPtables?

Answer (score 0):

`UseCanonicalName` is for the server hostname, not the client's.

This will work just fine in your global config, outside of any `VirtualHost`, as long as you don't have an `Order` directive in the vhosts:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from search.msn.com
```